# Using nvBLAS in R on Windows?

Tags: r, windows, nvblas

I am having trouble getting nvBLAS to work in R. I'm using RStudio on a Windows 10 machine, and I have no idea how to link nvBLAS and the original Rblas together for R to start up with both. From the nvBLAS documentation:

> To use the NVBLAS Library, the user application must be relinked
>   against NVBLAS in addition to the original CPU Blas (technically only
>   NVBLAS is needed unless some BLAS routines not supported by NVBLAS are
>   used by the application). To be sure that the linker links against the
>   exposed symbols of NVBLAS and not the ones from the CPU Blas, the
>   NVBLAS Library needs to be put before the CPU Blas on the linkage
>   command line.

How exactly do I do this in Windows? Caveat, I am a pretty solid R user, but I am by no means an R expert or a computer scientist. I would ideally like to avoid using an Ubuntu-build for this as well.